# Can not select a value in my client form and mark it as selected in Silvio Moreto ´s selectpicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Could you help me? I m working in a client CRUD in PHP, JS and AJAX but I am stuck.

My problem is in client edit form. When I click in edit client, all data of that client is loaded fine into the form, except one of the two selectpicker. I have two selectpicker, one for cities (#idprovincia) and the other for zones (#idmunicipio). When clicking on edit client the procedure should be:

1) Load all cities in #idprovincia selectpicker (works fine)
2) Load all zones of the selected city in #idmunicipio selectpicker (works fine)
3) Select and show as selected the client ´s zone in #municipio selectpicker.
The third point is not working.. I ´ve read about it but I can not find a correct solution for me, so i ´d appreciate your help.

I share my code for showing client data:

```
     function mostrar(idcliente)
    {
        $.post("../ajax/clientes.php?op=mostrar",{idcliente : idcliente}, function(data, status)
        {
            data = JSON.parse(data);        
            mostrarform(true);
            $("#idpago").val(data.idpago);
            $('#idpago').selectpicker('refresh');
            $("#idprovincia").val(data.idprovincia);
            $('#idprovincia').selectpicker('refresh');      
            $("#idmunicipio").val(data.idmunicipio);
            //$('#idmunicipio').selectpicker('refresh');
            $("#idcliente").val(data.idcliente);
            $("#tlfiscal").val(data.tlfiscal);
            $("#nombre").val(data.nombre);
            $("#zona").val(data.zona);
            $("#telefono").val(data.telefono);
            $("#movil").val(data.movil);
            $("#fax").val(data.fax);
            $("#contacto").val(data.contacto);
            $("#domicilio1").val(data.domicilio1);
            $("#cp").val(data.cp);      
            var provinciaID=data.idprovincia;       
            var municipioID = data.idmunicipio;
            var data = {'provinciaID': provinciaID};

#this ajax sends client ´s ID to another file and gets the list of zones of a city and loads them into (#idmunicipio) selectpicker

                $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'../ajax/clientes.php?op=selectMunicipio',
                        data: data,
                        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        success: function(data){
                        $("#idmunicipio").html(data);
                        $('#idmunicipio').selectpicker('refresh');
                        }

                    });

        })         

#now that I have all zones loaded I want to select the client ´s one and show it as selected in the user interface but this code doesn ´t work...
                $("#idmunicipio").val(municipioID);
                $('#idmunicipio').selectpicker('refresh');
    }`
```

Comment: So the problem here is that you don't know how to set selected ?

Comment: Yes @I.g.karolos , I need to asign as selected in #idmunicipio the value of var Municipio ID. i read about using val or value but I can not make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read from documentation

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerval

The right way to do this would be

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', 1);
```

For multiple values you can add array of values

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', [1 , 2]);
```

Comment: So for me it should be like this? : $('.idmunicipio').selectpicker('val', municipioID) and ; $('.idmunicipio').selectpicker('refres'); ?

Comment: Yeap I think so

Comment: Thanks @i.g.karolos , you helped me a lot. The solution was very close to yours. Just a little change and it is working this way: $('#idmunicipio').selectpicker('val', municipioID);

Answer (score 0):

So maybe as you select the option you could fill in the hidden input with the actually selected value?

Use **on('change') or addEventListener('change')** on any of them and fill input with the selected option (choose the value with the **:selected** selector).

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Can you give me an example @Kuba Wojtach please?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

Two lines at the end should be:

```
        $('#idmunicipio').selectpicker('val', municipioID);
        $('#idmunicipio').selectpicker('refresh');
```